# Connect to Azure Git Repository from Visual Studio 2012

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, azure-repos

I don't see the connect (electric plug) icon in Team Explorer on Visual Studio 2012 (which we have to use for BizTalk 2013). There's an option to connect to TFS (Team Foundation Server), but we want to connect to an Azure Repository.  Is that possible in VS2013, or do we have use command line maybe? Or is there an update pack or plug-in to allow it?

[image]

Comment: We downloaded this: Answer seems to be to download this: Git Source Control Provider https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yysun.GitSourceControlProvider but we don't see commit.  We mapped in "Source Control Explorer" and tried check-in.  Things in Solution Explorer have a + beside them, but we also see "no pending changes".

Comment: We still see 'Check-In", but not "Commit" in Solution Explorer.